# Sending pdf with Next.js + SendGrid will generate a corrupted file

Tags: next.js, twilio, sendgrid

I have a Next.js app, where I have a simple form with file input. I want to be able to attach this file in sendgrid and post it via email.

File input

```
<div>
  <form onSubmit={handleFileUpload}>
    <div>
      <label>select pdf file:</label>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileSelect} />
    </div>
    <button>upload</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Function handling the file input

```
const handleFileSelect = async (e: React.BaseSyntheticEvent) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const convertedFile = await toBase64(file);

    setSelectedFile(convertedFile);
  };
```

Function handling the file upload

```
  const handleFileUpload = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const req = await axios.post("/api/email", { file: selectedFile });
  };
```

Converting to base64 is done this way

```
const toBase64 = (file: File) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
    });
```

On the api side I have this code

```
export const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const attachment = req.body;
  const sgMail = sendgrid.setApiKey(apiKey);

  const message = {
    to: "email.com",
    from: "senderemail.com",
    subject: "Sending with sendGridxx",
    text: "I have added some text to work with.",
    attachments: [
      {
        content: attachment.file,
        filename: "content",
        type: "application/pdf",
        disposition: "attachment",
      },
    ],
  };

  sgMail
    .send(message)
    .then((val: any) => {
      console.log("email sent", val);
    })
    .catch((e: any) => console.log("error", e.response.body.errors));

  res.send({ file: attachment.file });
};
```

The email is sending correctly, but when I try to open the file it is corrupted.

Why is the file corrupted? How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your base64 string contains unnecessary characters. Try this one

```
const toBase64 = (file) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
      let encoded = reader.result.toString().replace(/^data:(.*,)?/, "");
      if (encoded.length % 4 > 0) {
        encoded += "=".repeat(4 - (encoded.length % 4));
      }
      resolve(encoded);
    };
    reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
  });
```